# How can I sort the comments by new, and stop my bot from commenting to the same comment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, reddit, praw

```
subreddit = reddit.subreddit("Gintama")

for post in subreddit.new():

    for comment in post.comments():
        if hasattr(comment,"body"):
            comment_lower = comment.body.lower()
            if " zura " in comment_lower:
                print("_________________")
                print(comment.body)
                comment.reply("Zura janai, Katsura da!!")
                comment.save
                time.sleep(600)
```

This is the code that I wrote. What I want to do is to sort the comments by "new". Then see that if there is any comment that says the keyword and reply to it.

When I ran this code, it replied to the same comment as it had the keyword and even replied to itself. How do I prevent this bot to reply to the same comment and stop replying to itself?

Comment: Could the problem be that you test for `" zura "` with a space before `zura`, while your reply starts with `"Zura"`, without a space? If the entire comment body is just `"zura janai..."`, `" zura "` will not be found in that string.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Sorry it was a mistake on my end. I pasted the corrected code here and after running the code it didnt reply to itself. That issue occured when I forgot to put a space before Zura in the if statement. Sorry again .

All that is left is to sort out the comments by new and stop replying to the same comment